# Android React Native old <application> values, vmSafeMode & largeHeap useful today?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm taking over a medium Android React-Native application which has not moved a lot since 2019.
One specific question I have is related to two parameters on the `<application>` declaration in AndroidManifest.xml.

I've searched what is does and it does not seems to be useful in my case (take photo, resize...).
However I'm a bit scared of removing them, I may not know what caused the developers before me to add them and the repercusion it could have on a lot of devices.

```
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        ...
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:vmSafeMode="true">
```

Does the community have some insight about a specific use case you may know in a React-Native project or any use case it may have been helpful?

Also, I think it may improve startup performance by removing vmSafeMode, but what about largeHeap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed those flags more than 6 months ago and did not have any negative impact on stability or performance.